# How to add tooltip text in js generated buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design, floating-action-button

I want to add tooltip text to the buttons in a Floating action button 
here.

[Sample JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/katrinluk/8wxho9cw/3/)

```
[{
    url: null,
    bgcolor: "red",
    icon: "+"
}, {
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    bgcolor: "orange",
    icon: "+"
}, {
    url: "http://www.example.com",
    bgcolor: "yellow",
    icon: "+"
}]
```

Comment: you can use jQuery UI

Comment: I guess Hint.css its a great option: http://kushagragour.in/lab/hint/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the most recent (and working) version. Try downloading the ZIP from GitHub (I downloaded `1d976c3` and it works) and opening index.html in your browser. It just needs a `title` attribute

```
var links = [
  {
    "bgcolor":"red",
    "icon":"+",
    "title": "Click me"
  },
  {
    "url":"http://www.example.com",
    "bgcolor":"red",
    "color":"#fffff",
    "icon":"<i class='fa fa-phone'></i>",
    "target":"_blank",
    "title": "Hey, Click me ..." // <--- This one
  },
  {
    "url":"http://www.example.com",
    "bgcolor":"black",
    "color":"white",
    "icon":"<i class='fa fa-music'></i>",
    "title":"Hey again, Click!" // <--- This one
  }
]

$('.kc_fab_wrapper').kc_fab(links);
```

Comment: Thank, the answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

For adding a `tooltip`, make use of HTML attribute - `title`, as following:

```
<div class="kc_fab_wrapper" title="Add new item"></div>
```